# Print file content without the first and last lines

Tags: text-processing

Is there a simple way I can echo a file, skipping the first and last lines? I was looking at piping from `head` into `tail`, but for those it seems like I would have to know the total lines from the outset. I was also looking at `split`, but I don't see a way to do it with that either.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Just with `sed`, without any pipes :

```
sed '1d;$d' file.txt
```

**NOTE**

- `1` mean *first line*
- `d` mean *delete*
- `;` is the separator for 2 commands
- `$` mean *last line*

More readable:

```
sed -e '1d' -e '$d' file.txt
```

Comment: Consise, but unreadable.

Answer (score 52):

You don't need to know the number of lines in advance. `tail` and `head` can take an offset from the beginning or end of the file respectively.

This pipe starts at the second line of the file (skipping the first line) and stops at the last but one (skipping the final line). To skip more than one line at the beginning or end, adjust the numbers accordingly.

```
tail -n +2 file.txt | head -n -1
```

doing it the other way round, works the same, of course:

```
head -n -1 file.txt | tail -n +2
```

Comment: I don't know why, but `head -n -1` removes the first AND the last line of my `.txt` file, on Ubuntu 14.04.2LTS.

Comment: On MacOS `head -n -1` says `head: illegal line count -- -1`

Comment: `head -n -1` works with GNU coreutils, maybe MacOS has some BSD variant?

Comment: Thank you! Combination of tail and head lets you select exactly the lines you need - just sweet!

Answer (score 12):

Here is how to do it with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR>2 {print t} {t=$0}'
```

Also another way for `sed`:

```
sed '1d;x' file.txt
```

`x` is advanced `sed` command, it switches current line with the previous one: current goes into the buffer and previous goes to the screen and so on while `sed` processing stream line by line (this is why the first line will be blank).

`awk` solution on each step (line) puts current line into the variable and starts printing it out only after the second line is passed by. Thus, we got shitfed sequence of lines on the screen from the second to the last but one. Last line is omitted becasue the line is in the variable and should be printed only on the next step, but all steps already run out and we never see the line on the screen.

Same idea in the `perl`:

```perl
perl -ne 'print $t if $.>2 ; $t=$_' file.txt
```

`$.` stands for line number and `$_`  for current line.
`perl -n` is shortcut for `while(<..>) {..}` structure and `-e` is for inline script.

Answer (score 4):

**For Mac users:**

On Mac, `head -n -1` doesn't work. Instead, reverse the file, chop off the first line, then reverse it back:

```
tail -r file.txt | tail -n +2 | tail -r
```

Explanation:

1. `tail -r` : reverses the order of lines in its input
2. `tail -n +2` : prints all the lines starting from the second line in its input

Comment: It would fail with `head: illegal line count -- -1` to be exact.

Comment: On Mac, you could install "coreutils" using "brew install". It allows you to use GNU commands. You just need to add 'g' add the beginning of the command. For example: instead of "head", type "ghead".

Answer (score 2):

In python i would do like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re
import sys
file = sys.argv[1]
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    L = []
    for line in f:
        line = re.sub(r'\n', r'', line)
        L.append(line)
    print('\n'.join(L[1:-1]))
```

Paste the above code into a file and name it as `script.py`. Run the script against the file you want to check with.

```
python3 script.py /path/to/the/file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
foo
apple
banana
bar
$ python3 script.py file
apple
banana
```

Comment: `''.join(list(open("/path/to/file"))[1:-1])` : This seems to be a simpler solution :-) And if you need it to be done on the command prompt directly, then you could try : `python -c 'print("".join(list(open("/path/to/file"))[1:-1]))'`